# BindingList members not updated from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I found a lot of questions and answers about updating a BindingList and having issues with updating the attached DataGridView, but my problem is the opposite and the answers don't seem to apply.

The BindingList is filled with types PanelSize:

```
public class PanelSize 
{
  public int PanelNumber { get; set; }
  public double Width { get; set; }
  public double Length { get; set; }
  public bool TerminatesLeft { get; set; }
  public bool TerminatesTop { get; set; }
  public bool TerminatesRight { get; set; }
  public bool TerminatesBottom { get; set; }
}
```

The DataGridView uses this BindingList as its DataSource.  (Panel Number is read-only, the bool's are checkboxes, and the doubles are text entries).

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = userPanelBindingList;
```

The behavior that I am seeing is that for the FIRST entry only in the DataGridView, if the user enters a Width and Length and does not check any of the bool values, the single entry in the BindingList shows the entered value for Width, but 0 for Length (when in fact there is a value there, e.g. 50.0).

If the user checks one of the boolean value check boxes, all the fields update correctly.

It's maddening.

To recap:  User enters: '50.0' for Width, '55.0' for Length, and does not check any of the 4 Terminates... booleans.  In the DataGridView.RowLeave event, userPanelBindingList[0].Width = 50.0, and userPanelBindingList[0].Height = 0.0.

I am interpreting the data in the RowLeave event, in effect using each new row entered in the DataGridView to run real-time calculations. Perhaps this is the wrong event in which to process?

Again, if the user enters Width=50.0, Length=55.0, and checks "Terminates Top", then all of the values are populated in the userPanelBindingList entry in the RowLeave event.

Any ideas what impossibly stupid thing I am doing or not doing to cause this behavior?

Thank you so much for any help.

Sean

Here is a short sample that I made in a new project to demonstrate the issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class PanelSize
    {
        public int PanelNumber;
        public double Width;
        public double Length;
        public bool TerminatesLeft;
        public bool TerminatesTop;
        public bool TerminatesRight;
        public bool TerminatesBottom;
    }

    private BindingList<PanelSize> bindingList;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingList = new BindingList<PanelSize>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingList;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (PanelSize sz in bindingList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Width: " + sz.Width);
            Console.WriteLine("Length: " + sz.Length);
        }
    }
```

Running the application, entering 50 for Width and 50 for Length and then going to a new line in the DataGridView, the Console Shows: Width: 50 Length: 0".  Doing it again but checking a box shows "Width: 50 Length: 50"

Comment: Sounds like there is code interfering somewhere.  BTW, `PanelNumber` is not read only

Comment: UPDATE: It's not just the first entry, it's any entry.  The boolean checkboxes need to be interacted with, or else the Width and Length fields are not properly updated from the DataGridView to the BindingList.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - the list contents update fine without help from the bools

Comment: Please post a simple code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Reza - I edited my original post to include the code from a new WinForm C# app that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks for any help